# Redirection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I Have the following code i am trying to redirect the page to the same page but with a int on the link but it keeps coming up with page error.

```
 var done_update = '&updated=1';
 window.location = window.location.href.done_update;
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var done_update = "&update=1";
location = location.href + done_update;
```

1. String concatenation in JavaScript is done using the `+` operator, not `.` as in other languages (Perl, PHP...)
2. `location` is a global variable, there is no need to specify `window.location`

Comment: I would say 2 is a personal preference.  I almost always use an explicit reference to window objects and properties, there's no risk of overriding them in local scopes that way.

Comment: If you put it that way it is reasonable to use `window.location`. However all global variables are properties of `window`, do you also use `window.document`?

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation is done in JavaScript (and Java for that matter) using a `+` and not a `.`:

```
var done_update = '&updated=1';
window.location = window.location.href + done_update;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var done_update = '&updated=1';
window.location = window.location.href+done_update;
```